# GVim Windows 7 PATH issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, vim, gvim

Interesting problem,

I had a gvim73 *distribution* running under Windows XP. Worked great.
Copied it to (it wasn't an installer, but an archive file + runtime files method of installation) Windows 7, put the according folder into the PATH environmental variable,

```
\...\gvim\vim73
```

and now, every time I run "Run" (WinKey+r) with "gvim" it opens up the folder,

```
\...\gvim
```

instead of running the application of the same name in the `vim73` folder (as it should, and as it is expected).

Has anyone *any* idea what could the source of this weird problem?

Answer (score 0):

The typical installation of GVIM is to put launcher scripts `gvim.bat` etc. into `%SystemRoot%`, not to add Vim's directory to the `PATH`. The `install.exe` that ships with Vim will do this for you. Maybe that helps.

Comment: No, not really ;) Besides, this principle I've described (and it's hardly new) works for every other program.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what run "Run" means, then this might offer some insight.

Windows binaries may be started with a "run in" parameter that specifies the "current folder" of the shell for the binary in question. In the screenshots below, you'll see that the listed folder will depend on how the binary was started. The first screenshot uses the default bat from the windows folder, the second is the "Properties" dialog of a launcher and in the third you see that the current folder is altered.

[image: original]
[image: properties]
[image: custom dir]

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that feature. Unfortunatelly, that only affects what folder will the application consider as its start folder. In my case, the application (GVim) is not run at all, but rather the folder named the same way ("gvim") is opened in windows explorer.

Comment: Okay, then I have clearly misunderstood the question. Put a gvim.bat somewhere in the PATH and use that. Would you like an example? Is `run "Run"` the win+r "run a single command" dialog? Please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Nobody else seems to have a problem with understanding the "run" thing. As far as gvim.bat goes, I see no point ... every other program behaves normally (even those named the same way as the directories they're in ... or vice versa). I'm interested why this is only happening with vim.